# The answer is right here silly

Tags: steganography, anagram

I need your help with this one. I had a mixup at work today.

[image]

As you can clearly see I missed part of my to do list today. 
Upon arriving at work, within minutes I received this email from my boss.

**What did I miss today?**

---

> Now, before you start your work in maya, 
>  One person pointed out
>   that you look like a fool. 
>  Tell me, is everything alright with
>   the misses? 
>  Let me guess, she kicked you out like a hobo? 
>  It
>   doesn't really matter though, but listen. 
>  Kidding aside, did you
>   lose the lotto? 
>  Err.. actual jokes aside, why not stay
>   at your apartment? 
>  Totally not cool to come in like that, heh.
>   
>  Haha sorry if laughing at you, but you've made a scene. 
>  In
>   my opinion, I don't mind what you (don't) wear, 
>  Should let us
>   know if this will continue in the future.

Sincerely,

- Gana Ram.

P.S. You're not usually one for playing jokes, why now?

Comment: everybody on here has nice handwriting :p

Comment: @indubitablee eh this isn't even my best handwriting but thanks

Comment: The first letters of the yellow section read "Not Like This", and the last reads "Also Not Here". The rest is obvious, but I'll let someone else type the answer

Comment: @EricLee the rest is obvious? How so

Comment: @indubitablee you haven't seen mine yet :P

Comment: The poem (I think) tells that you work for an ancient army. Like Mayans, Egyptians or so

Comment: Every line in the poem except the 2nd and last line has a comma and the lines before 2nd and last lines have 2 commas - just a pattern I observed

Comment: @padawan nope, it's not a poem and no knowledge needed

Comment: ... I *am* mad at you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As noted in the comments...

> The first and last letters of the sentences in the email spell out "Not like this" and "Also not here" respectively.  This indicates that the email doesn't contain the answer.

Where then?

> As the title mentions,  the answer is right there,  and we're being silly.  So we need to take the first letters of the title: TAIRHS and anagram them (Gana Ram), getting A SHIRT,  which is presumably what n_palum is missing.

Comment: Don't be too mad at me <3

Comment: I thought the 'checks' and 'crosses' on the paper's checkbox means something

Answer (score 5):

I would be surprised if this is right, but as was pointed out in the comments, Mr. Gana Ram left us a couple sentences within the letter.

The first line of each spells out *NOT LIKE THIS* and the last line spells out *also not here*.

> If you combine them together, they make an anagram that says **A Hellenise Shirt Took Not** which would indicate a lack of clothing, as was unchecked on the list of todos.

Comment: Kind of maybe not really the right idea? And no it's not right. Sp is correct that'd be silly of me to do

Comment: (Rewording/reposting comment:) When anagramming so many letters there's too many possible phrases that can be made, so I doubt this is the right approach due to a lack of confirmation

Comment: When I Google "hellenise", the top result is this question. Also, my spellchecker complains.

Comment: I can understand that I may not have exactly the answer that the OP was looking for (although it was actually in my answer), I am puzzled as to why the negative vote?

Comment: Hellenise is of or relating to hellenic (or greek) attire, which could be a shirt or such which covers the whole body...